# Accessing a Microsoft Access database on Windows server

Tags: database, ms-access, asp-classic

I have the unfortunate task of working with some legacy asp code and an Access database.

I've uploaded the .mdb file to the web server (which is windows) but when I enter the url into the browser, I get a 404 page. Seems that the server is not recognising the database.

Is this a problem anyone else has come across before?

Comment: what are you trying to do with the URL to the MS Access database?

Comment: A problem connecting to the database would not show up as a 404 error, but as some other kind of error thrown by the ASP script. And while I'm commenting, let me point out that Jet/ACE is not a very good database for running a website, unless it's read-only and/or has a very small number of users.

Comment: Yeah definitely not a good solution for running a site but it's not worth my while changing it - just dealing with what's already there unfortunately

Comment: Was trying to connect to the DB like so: Set Conn  = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("\mydb.mdb") & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=***;"
 Conn.open strConn but no luck with this, then tried just entering the mydb.mdb url into address bar to make sure it was reading it but it wasn't

Answer (score 0):

That's a file connection error. You're not going to open the .mdb file with your web browser.  You connect to the database in your ASP code.

Maybe you could show us some of the code and we could give you more specific answers?